# What legal action for auto shop cheating me?

Tags: fraud

I got a coupon for a free service, went to the repair shop in the chain to it have it done. The guy told me I need to pay extra. I was shown an itemized list which seemed to list things that should be there in the covered service already. It seemed too fishy to me, as there was a banner outside stating the price (which was lower than the coupon value). I declined the service, and went to another shop in the chain later. Here, they gladly accepted the work with no extra pay demanded. Then, I was told the coupon was already claimed when they tried to process it. The sketchy first place must be the one doing it. This chain is a franchise, and shops are managed by local owners. What can I do in this c to ase to this cheater? The guy second shop I went to is really nice. I got the printout stating that the coupon was claimed. Thanks.

Comment: Which state are you in?

Comment: I am in California.  I have the printout from the second shop that the coupon was used.

Answer (score 1):

Legally, some state consumer protection laws may come into play here - depending on your state; see [State Consumer Protection Offices | USAGov](https://www.usa.gov/state-consumer) - and there may be formal grievance processes after you fill out a complaint. And, nationally, there is the [Better Business Bureau](https://www.bbb.org/en/us/).

But for any complaint, you will have to present evidence or a strong case that you did not get the work done at the first shop and that your coupon wasn't fulfilled by them. It appears that it's a "he said, she said" situation with the local owner of the first shop. Unless the second shop would be willing to help and perhaps say that it appeared that no recent work was done to your vehicle.

You could take the first shop to [Small Claims Court - State Listing](http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/small-claims-court) in your county, but again, you will need evidence, and have to pay the filing fee and any other fees and schedule a court date. These may far outpace what you paid for the auto service itself.

Your best bet may be to contact the repair shops chain's national office. Any national retail chain will have an office to deal with complaints, and most will try hard to make good on bad situations, as their national reputation depends on having good customer relations. The national office may have limited oversight on the local shop, though. But the national office may make good on a valid coupon for the work as an ethical gesture.

Comment: What else can I do with the added info?

Comment: Start with http://www.dca.ca.gov/ and see what it takes to file a complaint. But the time and effort may outweigh the money you may save by getting a valid coupon.